# The request was aborted: The operation has timed out. on HttpWebResponse.Request.GetResponse()

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, fileserver

I have total of **12** continuous request and in the **6th** request I got this error. `The request was aborted: The operation has timed out.`(estimated time is 18 seconds). And After the **6th** request all of the remaining request is fast again. Why the 6th request is too slow compare to all other request?

This is my code:

```
 public bool CreateFolder(string _strDirectory)
    {
        bool result = true;
        System.Net.HttpWebRequest Request;
        CredentialCache MyCredentialCache;
        MyCredentialCache = new System.Net.CredentialCache();
        MyCredentialCache.Add(new System.Uri(_strDirectory), "NTLM", new System.Net.NetworkCredential(UserName, Password));
        Request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(_strDirectory);
        Request.Credentials = MyCredentialCache;
        Request.Method = "MKCOL";
        Request.Proxy = null;
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
        try
        {
            using (var response = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse())
            {
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        Request.Abort();
        return result;
    }
```

I also added to my Web.config this line of codes:

```
<system.net>
<connectionManagement>
  <clear/>
  <add address="*" maxconnection="1000000" />
</connectionManagement>
```

Any idea? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="90000" maxRequestLength="1048576" />
    ....
```

Also,

Add these:

```
request.KeepAlive = false;
request.Timeout = 50000;
request.ServicePoint.ConnectionLeaseTimeout = 50000;
request.ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime = 50000;
```

Comment: Base on my exception logs, the error still occurred `The request was aborted: The operation has timed out.` and the response time still 18 seconds.

Comment: That did the trick, i edited the 50000 to 500 so the timeout would be 5ms not 50 secs as max.

Comment: @JAlcantara Glad I could help. Peace and love from Israel.

Answer (score 0):

This is my final code from 18 seconds to 5ms. I also added Garbage Collect in the end of the code.

```
    public bool CreateFolder(string _strDirectory)
    {
        bool result = true;

        System.Net.HttpWebRequest Request;
        CredentialCache MyCredentialCache;
        MyCredentialCache = new System.Net.CredentialCache();
        MyCredentialCache.Add(new System.Uri(_strDirectory), "NTLM", new System.Net.NetworkCredential(UserName, Password));
        Request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(_strDirectory);
        Request.Credentials = MyCredentialCache;
        Request.Method = "MKCOL";
        Request.KeepAlive = false;
        Request.Timeout = 500;
        Request.Proxy = null;

        Request.ServicePoint.ConnectionLeaseTimeout = 500;
        Request.ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime = 500;

        try
        {
            using (var response = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse())
            {
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
        Request.Abort();
        GC.Collect();
        return result;
    }
```